# form ng-submit loads a sub-view, but only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ngroute

So basically I have a web page 'Index' which has a form, and a ng-view section.
So what I want is for the user to fill out some fields in the form and submit it, ng-view is rendered beneath the form with the results from the server trip.

And it works! When this view loads it hits the server with the values filled out from the form, returns data and renders it to the page.

The issue I have is that this only works ONCE.

Fill out the form, hit submit, the results page loads beneath it.
Change the values in the form and submit it again and it will not fire the query back to the server.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
It's my first angular app and I've been figuring things out as I go along - so I'm not even sure this is the accepted way to do things.

Bonus question: Can anyone tell me why my whole browser crashes when the `*//$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/Reports/Index' });*` line is uncommented?

This is all the relevant code:

```
//The main index page.
<div ng-app="ReportsApp" ng-controller="indexFormsCtrl" class="form-inline">

    <!-- Our main input form -->
    <form ng-submit="search()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="mySearchField" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>

//Main routing secion
angular.module('ReportsApp', ['ReportsApp.ctrl.bonus', 'ReportsApp.ctrl.index', 'ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        //When this is present it will make the page crash - like it is stuck in an infinite loop
        //commented out the site works, but it redirects me to /squiffy
        //$routeProvider.when('/', {
            //templateUrl: '/Reports/Index',
        //});
        $routeProvider.when('/MyReport', {
            templateUrl: '/Reports/MyReport',
            controller: 'myReportCtrl',
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/squiffy'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
    }])

//The index controller - not much to see other than the location.path redirect.
angular.module('ReportsApp.ctrl.index', []).controller('indexFormsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, reportsService) {
    $scope.mySearchField = '';

    $scope.search = function()
    {
        reportsService.mySearchField = $scope.toDate;
        //redirect the view to MyReport
        $location.path('MyReport')
    }
});

//the report contents controller (ng-view controller). Hits the server, gets some json, stores it in $scope
angular.module('ReportsApp.ctrl.bonus', []).controller('myReportCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, reportsService) {
    $scope.myModel = null;
    getTheReportData(reportsService);
    //Get the bonus overview
    function getTheReportData(reportsService) {
        alert('searching');
        $scope.myModel = GetDataFromServer(reportsService.mySearchField);
    };
});
```

I am assuming it is because the data is loaded when the controller is initialized. And it only gets initialized when the page first loads, not on subsequent submits.

Comment: Try $routeProvider.when('/', '/Reports/Index');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your view isn't reloaded is because of some optimizations done by $location. If the path doesn't change, the page won't be reloaded. The way to get around this is by using

```
$route.reload();
```

However your code could also use some more organization... Instead of tying the server request to loading a controller, why not move the server-requesting code to your search function? Better yet, you could create a service to handle your HTTP requests that is re-usable in every controller. Read more about angular services [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Regarding your second question: your browser crashes when you uncomment that line because the route object that you're passing to the $routeProvider requires a controller.

Your route should be the following, but replace 'controllerName' with your actual controller.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/Reports/Index',
    controller: 'controllerName'
});
```